# "Supported groups" in RFC 8446 (TLS 1.3)

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, finite-field, terminology

What is meant by "supported groups" in the section 4.2.7. "Supported Groups" of RFC 8446:
/* Finite Field Groups (DHE) */
ffdhe2048(0x0100), ffdhe3072(0x0101), etc:
Is the digits - 2048, 3072 (and groups) etc - are simply numbers of bits of the parameter *p* (module) in DF algorythm or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are referring to the parameters required to perform DH operations. For (EC)DH operations it takes a long time compute a set of secure parameters. Hence the parameters are "named" and then referenced using the name, an OID, or in the case of TLS, a set of two bytes (or one 16-bit word) that indicate the parameters used. This also cuts down on communication overhead, of course.

The key agreement operation is then performed with a non generic-public / private key value and the required set of parameters. This derives the master secret, the master key and finally the session keys that are used to encrypt the messages.

The standard itself references [RFC 7919](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919):

> Finite Field Groups (DHE):  Indicates support for the corresponding
> finite field group, defined in [[RFC7919]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919#appendix-A).  Values 0x01FC through
> 0x01FF are reserved for Private Use.

In particular [Appendix A](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919#appendix-A), which lists all the required parameters values for the various groups. The parameters themselves are usually present in the various cryptographic libraries and can be retrieved using a mapping name -> map of parameter values.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> Is the digits - 2048, 3072 (and groups) etc - are simply numbers of bits of the parameter p (module) in DF algorythm or something else ?

These names are references to the groups defined in RFC 7919; the actual digits refer to the number of bits within the prime modulus.  For example, ffdhe2048 uses a 2048 bit prime modulus.

Comment: Thank you very much!